# How to change pivot table data source in Excel?

Tags: excel, business-intelligence, xls, pivot-table

I want to change it from one database to another.

There don't appear to be any options to do this on the pivot table context menu

Comment: How this is off topic?! I'm a BI developer and seems like a lot of other people have coming looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right click on the pivot table in excel
choose wizard
click 'back'
click 'get data...'
in the query window
File - Table Definition

then you can create a new or choose a different connection

Comment: no such menu option in Excel 2007

Answer (score 21):

Just figured it out-click anywhere in the table, then go to the tabs at the top of the page and select Options-from there you'll see a Change Data Source selection.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like this depends heavily on your version of Excel. I am using the 2007 version and it offers no wizard option when you right click on the table. You need to click on the pivot table to make extra 'PivotTable Tools' appear to the right of the other tabs at the top of the screen. Click the 'options' tab that appears here then there is a big icon on the middle of the ribbon named 'change data source'.

Answer (score 3):

In order to change the data source from the ribbon in excel 2007...

Click on your pivot table in the worksheet.  Go to the ribbon where it says Pivot Table Tools,  Options Tab.  Select the Change Data Source button.  A dialog box will appear.

To get the right range and avoid an error message... select the contents of the existing field and delete it, then switch to the new data source worksheet and highlight the data area (the dialog box will stay on top of all windows).  Once you've selected the new data source correctly, it will fill in the blank field (which you deleted before) in the dialog box.  Click OK.  Switch back to your pivot table and it should have updated with the new data from the new source.

Answer (score 2):

- Right click on the pivot table, choose PivotTable Wizard.
- Click the 'back' button twice.
- Choose External Data Source,click next.
- Click Get Data
- In the first tab, Databases the first option is 'New Data Source'

Comment: This does not work. There is no getdata button on the 'choose external data source' page of the wizard. And if you do click 'get data' on the next page, there is no immediately obvious way of editing the connection

Answer (score 2):

This Add-on will do the trick for you.

http://www.contextures.com/xlPivotPlayPlus01.html

It shows the connection string, and allows it to be changed.
Don't forget to change the Query SQL as well, if needed (with the same tool).

Answer (score 2):

Be a bit wary of any solution that doesn't involve re-creating the PivotTable from scratch.  It is possible for your pivot fields' option names to get out of sync with the values they present to the database.

For example, in one workbook I'm dealing with involving demographic data, if you try to select the "20-24" age band option, Excel actually presents you with the figures for ages 25-29.  It doesn't tell you it's doing this, of course.

See below for a programmatic (VBA) approach to the problem that solves this issue among others.  I think it's fairly complete/robust, but I don't use PivotTables much so would appreciate feedback.

```
Sub SwapSources()

strOldSource = "2010 Data"
strNewSource = "2009 Data"

Dim tmpArrOut

For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pvt In wsh.PivotTables
        tmpArrIn = pvt.SourceData
        ' row 1 of SourceData is the connection string.
        ' rows 2+ are the SQL code broken down into 255-byte chunks.
        ' we need to concatenate rows 2+, replace, and then split them up again

        strSource1 = tmpArrIn(LBound(tmpArrIn))
        strSource2 = ""
        For ii = LBound(tmpArrIn) + 1 To UBound(tmpArrIn)
            strSource2 = strSource2 & tmpArrIn(ii)
        Next ii

        strSource1 = Replace(strSource1, strOldSource, strNewSource)
        strSource2 = Replace(strSource2, strOldSource, strNewSource)

        ReDim tmpArrOut(1 To Int(Len(strSource2) / 255) + 2)
        tmpArrOut(LBound(tmpArrOut)) = strSource1
        For ii = LBound(tmpArrOut) + 1 To UBound(tmpArrOut)
            tmpArrOut(ii) = Mid(strSource2, 255 * (ii - 2) + 1, 255)
        Next ii

        ' if the replacement SQL is invalid, the PivotTable object will throw an error
        Err.Clear
        On Error Resume Next
            pvt.SourceData = tmpArrOut
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Problems changing SQL for table " & wsh.Name & "!" & pvt.Name
            pvt.SourceData = tmpArrIn ' revert
        ElseIf pvt.RefreshTable <> True Then
            MsgBox "Problems refreshing table " & wsh.Name & "!" & pvt.Name
        Else
            ' table is now refreshed
            ' need to ensure that the "display name" for each pivot option matches
            ' the actual value that will be fed to the database.  It is possible for
            ' these to get out of sync.
            For Each pvf In pvt.PivotFields
                'pvf.Name = pvf.SourceName
                If Not IsError(pvf.SourceName) Then ' a broken field may have no SourceName
                    mismatches = 0
                    For Each pvi In pvf.PivotItems
                        If pvi.Name <> pvi.SourceName Then
                            mismatches = mismatches + 1
                            pvi.Name = "_mismatch" & CStr(mismatches)
                        End If
                    Next pvi
                    If mismatches > 0 Then
                        For Each pvi In pvf.PivotItems
                            If pvi.Name <> pvi.SourceName Then
                                pvi.Name = pvi.SourceName
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            Next pvf
        End If
    Next pvt
Next wsh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> right click on the pivot table in
>   excel choose wizard click 'back' click
>   'get data...' in the query window File
>   - Table Definition
>
> then you can create a new or choose a
>   different connection

worked perfectly.

the get data button is next to the tiny button with a red arrow next to the range text input box.

Answer (score 1):

for MS excel 2000 office version, 
click on the pivot table
you will find a tab above the ribon, called Pivottable tool - click on that
You can change data source from Data tab

Answer (score 1):

In case of Excel 2007 You can change datasource in Options menu /Change Data Source